# Определить какой фон под div на jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, header, background

Как определить какой фон под нашим фиксированным div (лучше, если это будет на jquery)?

В шапке сайта есть фиксированное лого. При прокрутке оно должно меняться с белого на черное в зависимости от фона, который находится под ним, когда скролим странницу.

**Обновление**

Пример – www.designbyface.com/ (черная иконка справа вверху). Когда скролим – на темном фоне должна становиться белой, ведь так ее не видно, нечитабельна.

Слева так же должно быть размещено фиксированное лого в png, а при скроле будет меняться png с черной картинки на белую и наоборот. Это только пример, а сайт - динамический, страницы разные.

Comment: Хоть какой то пример есть? "Под нашим" это под каким? Здесь провидцев нет, да и мысли никто не читает. Добавьте код с помощью правки вашего вопроса

Comment: Что значит `какой фон`? Какой цвет или картинка? Что значит под `нашим фиксированным div`? Пытайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы с примером что есть и что хотите получить

Comment: а если половина иконки на черном фоне, а половина на белом?

Comment: мне кажется, правильнее просчитать, пускай и для каждой страницы, кол-во пикселей, которые надо проскролить, чтобы логотип поменял цвет. и динамически подключать функцию смены лого в нужный момент

Comment: может такой вариант подойдет? http://aerolab.github.io/midnight.js/

Comment: @WebNata, вероятно вам этот подход нравится как крутое дизайнерское решение, но вы не рассматриваете вариант выделить меню контрастной рамкой? типа `border: 1pt solid silver;` Потеряется "вау-эффект", зато будет просто и стильно, и меню не сольется с темным фоном

Answer (score 1):

Прямо под логотипом - вряд-ли, а получить цвета рядом, кажется, можно.

## Решение:

1. Есть проект [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) - с его помощью можно сделать canvas-копию куска страницы. Нас интересует кусок - верхние 100px. Делаем js-ом "скриншот" в canvas.
2. Есть способ получить данные об RGB-представлении куска canvas - [getImageData()](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/canvas_getimagedata.asp). Вы знаете отступы логотипа сверху и справа от границы окна, вычленяете эту область.
3. Анализируете цвета в выделенной области выше, ниже, слева, справа от логотипа и сравниваете с цветом посередине логотипа.
4. По результатам сравнения (например, 3 или 4 совпавших с центром контрольных точек) меняете логотип на инвертированную версию.

### P.S: Определить под логотипом цвет светлее или темнее - можно

В теории, можно логотип сделать частично прозрачным, к нему будет примешиваться цвет фона, затем смотреть изменение цвета центрального пикселя - стал он темнее эталона или светлее. Или даже на страницу его добавлять с помощью canvas и [drawImage()](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/canvas_drawimage.asp), что позволит избежать использования библиотеки html2canvas.

Comment: Неожиданное для меня решение, а вы сможете такое реализовать?

Comment: @WebsNata, думаю, да, ведь по отдельности эти возможности приходилось когда-то использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант без математики и геометрии.
Менять картинку js-кой каждую долю секунды.
Только надо довольно маленький период чтобы глазу было незаметно.
Либо у картинки сделать кромку.

На мой взгляд такие мелочи не должны иметь сложных решений.

Comment: Менять картинку я умею, а вот интересует именно как задать if. Т.е. как составить такое выражение, которое будет означать светлый или темный фон под div при скроле. Страницы на сайте разные, их много, нет возможности для каждой писать код. Т.е. интересует именно выражение для автоматики.

Comment: То есть интересна именно задача определения фона?

Comment: Да, верно. Знаете какие-то методы?

Comment: Нет. к сожалению, не сталкивался с этим. Поддержу предыдущих ораторов. =)

Answer (score 0):

Можете воспользоваться document.elementFromPoint(). Пример:
https://preview.c9users.io/dmvw34/logorecalc/logo.html